# When should I use non-member operator overloading?

Tags: c++

Should I be using non-member overload or member overload? How do I tell which I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're thinking about something like `operator<` or `swap`, there's a rule of thumb ( though it's not terribly strict or mandatory):

If the function only requires access to the public interface of your class, make it a free non-member function. Otherwise make it a member function. (Alternatively you may consider a `friend` free function.)

Note that for overloads of operators you will need at least one of the operands to be a user-defined type.

The design advantage of a free function is that you can make it a template and get `M + N` complexity rather than `M * N` if you were to implement a version of the operator for each class for which it's applicable. This may or may not be relevant to your situation.

See also [Nawaz's very fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821315/when-should-i-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions/7821482#7821482) on the subject.