# C++11 - how to make this Qt statement in C++11?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++11

In Qt C++ they use like this:

```
QtCUrl::Options opt;
QStringList headers;
headers
    << "Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    << "Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate"
    << "Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
    << "User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
opt[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = headers;
```

But, i cant use Qt libraries, so how do i do that same declaration of `headers`  in C++11?

Comment: NO, only like QStringList correct.

Comment: Look at using std::StringStream

Comment: look for std::vector<std::string> headers;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First choice:

```
using namespace std; 
list<string> headers;
    headers.push_back("Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    headers.push_back("Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate");
    headers.push_back("Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    headers.push_back("User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0");
```

Second choice:

```
using namespace std; 
vector<string> headers;
    headers.push_back("Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    headers.push_back("Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate");
    headers.push_back("Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    headers.push_back("User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0");
```

Comment: How can you use `<<` ?

Comment: << is equal to push_back, they mean "insert a element at the end of a queue"

Comment: P.s.: you can define "<<" operator following this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411733/use-operator-to-push-stdstrings-in-a-vector  ;)