# C++ How To Access Member Variables Through A CallBack Method

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback, static-methods, friend

I'm using SQLite's `sqlite3_exec` function with Static CallBack functions to handle some information. I want to print out the resulting information to a file defined in a class that called `sqlite3_exec`. What I'm talking about looks kinda like this,

```cpp
class MakingTheCall{

static int CallBack(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < argc; x++)
        File << argv[x];
    File<<"\n";
} 

private:
   static ofstream File;
   void call(){
       sqlite3_exec(database, query, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   }
};
```

what I **REALLY** want is for the static function to use a instance specific `FILE`. So which ever instance of `MakingTheCall` makes the call passes it's unique non-static `FILE` object.

But because `CallBack` is static and must be (I think) to be a callback it doesn't get access to the `this` pointer of the class. So my thought is if the function where a `friend` function then it could get at the `this` pointer. This is assuming I'm understanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315264/839501) post correctly.

I feel my line of thinking is flawed. It feels like there might still be ambiguity as to which `this` the function would be using.

As a Part 2 to this discussion is there an example anywhere of where a static friend method would ever be used? They aren't mutually exclusive modifiers from what I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2315166/839501) on the first comment so when would you use both?

I'm new to SQLite and to CallBacks so chances are I could be missing something here that could make my life easy. Like the `void*` pointer how do I use that? It feels like the key to what I want to do.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the object pointer in the `sqlite3_exec()` call:

```
sqlite3_exec(database, query, callback, (void*) this, &zErrMsg);
```

And you'll get it back in the callback's `NotUsed` parameter:

```
static int CallBack(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    MakingTheCall* obj = (MakingTheCall*) NotUsed;

    // whatever....
}
```

Strictly speaking, the `Callback()` function should be an `extern "C"` free function, not a static member.

Comment: It might be a good idea to rename the parameter, since it is used now.

Comment: +1 I was going to write the same, although the name of the parameter in my version was `NowUsed`

Comment: Awesome. I was wondering how to use the void*. Now I feel like I need to change the Title of the question doesn't really have anything to do with the actual answer. Any chance you could speak about `static friend` methods being I am super curious about where that would work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are compiling with `C++11`-support, you can use an anonymous function (lambda expression).
Example:

```
class MakingTheCall
{
private:
   ofstream File;
   void call(){
       sqlite3_exec(database, query,
           [&] (void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) -> int
           {
               for(int x = 0; x < argc; x++)
               File << argv[x];
               File<<"\n";
           },
           0, &zErrMsg);
   }
};
```

`[&]` means, that all variables available in `call` are captured by reference, including the `this`-pointer. See [here(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B) for details.

Comment: You can't use a capture group when the lambda is being casted as a function pointer. This is why the "1st argument to callback" parameter was included in `sqlite3_exec()`. I tried adding `std::function` support to sqlite3, but I failed due to too many `void*` conversions and a high level of impatience when changing the library from C to C++.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, this is acheived by passing a pointer to the object in as part of a *closure* parameter when registering the callback. In the case of `sqlite3_exec` the API is as follows:

```
int sqlite3_exec(
  sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

So I'd pass the pointer to the object in as parameter 4. Your callback function is still static but the first thing it should do is cast the first parameter as a pointer to the class of the object you're interested in. You can then call the desired function which would allow you to write to a `File` which is specific to the instance you've been passed. So your code might lookk a littel like this:

```
static int CallBack(void *closure, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    MakingTheCall* obj = static_cast<MakingTheCall*>(closure);
    obj->WriteToTheFile(argc, argv);
    return 0; // Have to return something.
}

int WriteToTheFile(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < argc; x++)
        File << argv[x];
    File<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the `static_cast` instead of a regular `(MakingTheCall*)(Closure);` cast?

Comment: @Dan: Mainly because this is C++, not C. Please check out Konrad Rudolphs answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles